# Signature does not match - POST HTTP Request to BingX API with Python

Tags: python, post, signature, hashlib

I'm trying to communicate with an API of a Tradingplatform via post requests in Python. Unfortunately, this only works if the request does not have to be signed. At the beginning I just wanted to follow the example of the documentation ([BingX API Documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/bingx-exchange/docs/blob/master/Perpetual_Swap_API_Documentation.md#signature)) to get an account balance. The example gave me the impression that this would take half an hour, but now i've been at it for two days and i'm slowly starting to despair.

When I send my request I get an error message from the server that my signature is not correct:

> {"code":80014,"msg":"signature not match","data":{}}

Since i have no experience with encryption or similar things, it is very difficult for me to analyze the error. I could imagine that the error lies in the conversion to bytes, but i can't omit this step for test purposes either. The documentation asks you to encrypt the string according to this scheme:

```
Signature = HmacSHA256("UuGuyEGt6ZEkpUObCYCmIfh0elYsZVh80jlYwpJuRZEw70t6vomMH7Sjmf94ztSI", "POST/api/v1/user/getBalanceapiKey=Zsm4DcrHBTewmVaElrdwA67PmivPv6VDK6JAkiECZ9QfcUnmn67qjCOgvRuZVOzU&currency=USDT&timestamp=1615272721001")
Signature = Base64Encode(Signature)
Signature = UrlEncode(Signature)
```

Which i "solved" as follows:

```
signature       =   hmac.new(api_secret.encode('utf-8'), originstring.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest().upper()
signature       =   str(signature)
signature       =   bytes(signature, 'utf-8')
signature       =   base64.b64encode(signature)
signature       =   urllib.parse.quote(signature)
```

I would be very happy if someone could explain to me what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks very much

Daniel

**My full Python Code:**

```
import requests
import hmac
import hashlib
import time
import base64
import urllib
import json

api_key         =   "tHeKeY"
api_secret      =   "MySuPeRsEcReT"
asset           =   "USDT"
want            =   "getBalance"

timestamp       =   str(int(time.time()))

paramstring     =   (str("apiKey=")     +
                    str(api_key)        +
                    str("&currency=")   +
                    str(asset)          +
                    str("&timestamp=")  +
                    str(timestamp))

print("PARAMSTRING:")
print(paramstring)
print("")

originstring    =   (str("POST/api/v1/user/") +
                    str(want) +
                    str(paramstring))

print("ORIGINSTRING:")
print(originstring)
print("")

signature       =   hmac.new(api_secret.encode('utf-8'), originstring.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest().upper()
signature       =   str(signature)
signature       =   bytes(signature, 'utf-8')
signature       =   base64.b64encode(signature)
signature       =   urllib.parse.quote(signature)

print("SIGNATURE:")
print(signature)
print("")

signature = str(signature)

requeststring   =   (str("https://api-swap-rest.bingbon.pro/api/v1/user/getBalance?") +
                    str("apiKey=")      +
                    str(api_key)        +
                    str("&currency=")   +
                    str(asset)          +
                    str("&timestamp=")  +
                    str(timestamp)      +
                    str("&sign=")       +
                    str(signature))

print("REQUESTSTRING:")
print(requeststring)
print("")
print("RESPONSE:")

response            =   requests.post(requeststring)
response            =   str(response.text)
print(response)
response            =   json.loads(response)
response_code       =   (response["code"])
response_message    =   (response["msg"])
response_data       =   (response["data"])

print(response_code)
print(response_message)
print(response_data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infinite monkeys with infinite typewriters, with enough time you can experiment.

I have no idea why, but when I do it this way it works:

```
signature       =   (base64.b64encode(
                hmac.new(bytes(api_secret, 'utf-8'), bytes(originstring, 'utf-8'),digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()).decode("utf-8"))
```

But anyway, if someone can tell me where my problem was, it would be great. Because for me both solutions look somehow the same.

Answer (score 0):

Incase someone still has issues with BingX API, heres a Link to some demo wrappers for python/php/postman/java/go. Incase the git gets removed il add some example code here aswell.
https://github.com/BingX-API/BingX-swap-api-doc/tree/master/demo

**Python**

```
import urllib.request
import json
import base64
import hmac
import time

APIURL = "https://api-swap-rest.bingbon.pro"
APIKEY = "Set your api key here !!"
SECRETKEY = "Set your secret key here!!"

def genSignature(path, method, paramsMap):
    sortedKeys = sorted(paramsMap)
    paramsStr = "&".join(["%s=%s" % (x, paramsMap[x]) for x in sortedKeys])
    paramsStr = method + path + paramsStr
    return hmac.new(SECRETKEY.encode("utf-8"), paramsStr.encode("utf-8"), digestmod="sha256").digest()

def post(url, body):
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, data=body.encode("utf-8"), headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    return urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()

def getBalance():
    paramsMap = {
        "apiKey": APIKEY,
        "timestamp": int(time.time()*1000),
        "currency": "USDT",
    }
    sortedKeys = sorted(paramsMap)
    paramsStr = "&".join(["%s=%s" % (x, paramsMap[x]) for x in sortedKeys])
    paramsStr += "&sign=" + urllib.parse.quote(base64.b64encode(genSignature("/api/v1/user/getBalance", "POST", paramsMap)))
    url = "%s/api/v1/user/getBalance" % APIURL
    return post(url, paramsStr)
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

$url = "https://api-swap-rest.bingbon.pro";
$apiKey = "Set your api key here!!";
$secretKey = "Set your secret key here!!";

function getOriginString(string $method, string $path, array $params) {
    // combine origin string
    $originString = $method.$path;
    $first = true;
    foreach($params as $n => $v) {
          if (!$first) {
              $originString .= "&";
          }
          $first = false;
          $originString .= $n . "=" . $v;
    }
    return $originString;
}

function getSignature(string $originString) {
    global $secretKey;
    $signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $originString, $secretKey, true);
    $signature = base64_encode($signature);
    $signature = urlencode($signature);
    return $signature;
}

function getRequestUrl(string $path, array $params) {
    global $url;
    $requestUrl = $url.$path."?";
    $first = true;
    foreach($params as $n => $v) {
          if (!$first) {
              $requestUrl .= "&";
          }
          $first = false;
          $requestUrl .= $n . "=" . $v;
    }
    return $requestUrl;
}

function httpPost($url)
{
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "curl/7.80.0");
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $response;
}

function getBalance() {
    global $apiKey;

    // interface info
    $path = "/api/v1/user/getBalance";
    $method = "POST";

    // interface params
    $params = array();
    $params['currency'] = 'USDT';
    $params['apiKey'] = $apiKey;
    $date = new DateTime();
    $params['timestamp'] = $date->getTimestamp()*1000;

    // sort params
    ksort($params);

    // generate signature
    $originString = getOriginString($method, $path, $params);
    $signature = getSignature($originString);
    $params["sign"] = $signature;

    // send http request
    $requestUrl = getRequestUrl($path, $params);
    $result = httpPost($requestUrl);
    echo "\t";
    echo $result;
    echo "\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As of [2023-06-03](https://bingx-api.github.io/docs/#/swapV2/changelog) this method does not work properly. BingX has updated their API and use a different kind of signature. To quote from the [BingX Perpetual Futures API signature documentation](https://bingx-api.github.io/docs/#/swapV2/authentication.html#Signature):

> The signature request parameter is encrypted using the HMAC SHA256 method.

This is how I made it work for me:

```py
def bingx_sign(params):
    digest = hmac.new(SECRET_KEY.encode("utf-8"), params.encode("utf-8"), digestmod="sha256").digest()
    return digest.hex()
```

Here is my open source implementation of the Perpetual Futures API: [py-bingx](https://github.com/amirinsight/py-bingx)